# Office Add-ins Javascript - How to simulate tab or enter key to choose cell inside a range

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel Office Add-ins, I need to select a range, and read the data from each cell of that range when I press Tab key or Enter key (to highlight cell from left to right, top to button). How do I read the highlight cells? The Excel.Range class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview doesn't have anything like that. Thank you!

Comment: it seems you would like to change the active cell of the range. may I know what would you do when you get the active cell？

Comment: @RaymondLu I use each cell to speak out, it is text to speech, but in Vietnamese, I can get the cell content but cannot traverse all the cells in the selected range. Thank you!

Comment: @RaymondLu Can you show me how to get the active cell inside a range? Thank you!

Comment: I would like to learn more about your scenario, and see how we can unblock the scenario. so I am interested in what you would need to do next after you get the active cell of the range.

Comment: @RaymondLu The requirement is from my College's teacher. He wants a feature that when he chooses a range, including a student name column and the corresponding score, he wants to speak each cell everytime he click a button on the taskpane from the Office Add-in I am developing. That's why I ask for traverse through  the cells in a range. Thank you!

Comment: if in this case, can you use range.getOffsetRange(rowOffset, columnOffset) to get a range object for a cell and then you could range.select() to change the active cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Office JS does not provide a method to change an active cell in a range object, based on your description of the scenario, we have a workaround solution for your scenario.

You could get the range of the cell after the end-user clicks the button by `range.getOffsetRange(rowOffset, columnOffset)` and then you could use that range object of this cell to set it active, therefore it would be able to TTS

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const range = context.workbook.getActiveCell();
    var activeCell = range.getOffsetRange(0,1);
    activeCell.select();

    await context.sync();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! Hope the feature will be available in the future.